# Error in for loop in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, statistics

I am working with a data frame called bumpus. When I try to select only certain rows using `for` and `if` statements I get an error:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in "for(i in 1:(nrow(bumpus)){"
```

Could you please help me to figure out what is it that I am missing? Here is my for loop:

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(bumpus)) {
    if(bumpus[i,2]=="m")
    {
    bumpus_males<-bumpus[i,]
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you get Eclipse+StatET or ESS to help you with your syntax writing. It will save you A LOT of time.

Comment: I like notepad++ too. Basically any text editor that allows you to show which opening and closing paranthese belong together is extremely useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Count your parentheses (or use a good editor that helps with matching).

You have 3 openening parens, then only 2 closing before the 1st brace ({), you need one more closing paren before the brace to match the one for the for condition.

Also, you can do this much simpler with the ifelse function and not need the loop.

Comment: I can't think of an error message in R that is more clear than "unexpected ..."

Answer (score 4):

Greg solved your problem, but your code still looks funny. As written (with Greg's correction), your loop will work through each row, and if the row has "m" in the second column, it will replace bumpus_males with *just that row*. So if more than one row has "m" in the second column, you'll only get the last row saved as bumpus_males. I suspect what you really want here is more like:

```
bumpus_males <- subset(bumpus, bumpus[,2] == "m")
```

This will create a new data.frame with all the rows where column 2 is "m".

Comment: yeah, it only does one row. I mean it writes it over. Been a while since i've done any kind of programming. Thank you guys.